# moq.verify - generic method tested with base type when inherited type is used

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

How do I verify that that a call was made to a generic method using an inherited type when I can only check for the base type.

I have am Interface with a generic method:

```
public interface IEvent
{
   void Subscribe<T>() where T : BaseEvent;
}
```

My code has several derived events that inherit from BaseEvent. Here is one:

```
public class  DerivedEvent: BaseEvent{}
```

I call subscribe as follows:

```
myEvent.Subscribe<DerivedEvent>()
```

In a unit test I want to verify that the call is made with any class that derives from base Event.
This will pass, but it's using the derivied class.

```
v.Subscribe<DerivedEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));
```

This gets called zero times:

```
v.Subscribe<BaseEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));
```

How do I verify that the generic method Subscribe was called with any BaseEvent?

Comment: Side note: it is somewhat strange that any event source (which for some reason called `IEvent`) can fire all possible events... Consider if `IEventSource<out TEvent>` will work better ([out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier))... and then you'll not need this strange test.

Comment: It's not really called IEvent - I just shortened the name for the post (Same with BaseEvent and DerivedEvent).    This is a unit test for code that is not yet written.  The code must call Subscribe with a BaseEvent, but the code itself will use a class that derives from BaseEvent.  There will only be one event, but at test creation time I don't know the Class.

Comment: But this actually should work...:/ `myEvent.Verify(m => m.Subscribe<BaseEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));` is this what you are calling?

Comment: @DonChambers I', confused about "The code must call Subscribe with a BaseEvent, but the code itself will use a class that derives from BaseEvent." - sample code may help... I don't think Moq supports "see if any other concrete versions of generic method were not called" case... It may be easier to just create test class that implement your "IEvent" interface and somehow exposes list of subscribers to verify later (instead of mocking it).

Comment: The github example is when passing a generic parameter.  Mine is calling a generic method.  I tried:
v.Subscribe<DerivedEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));

It didn't work.
Am I missing something?

Comment: @DonChambers more info on what I think you are trying to do - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+moq+mock+open+type (and answer seem to be no).

Comment: @DonChambers I tried and it worked, could you share what is `v`, could you update the answer and post the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I verify that the generic method `Subscribe` was called with any `BaseEvent`?

Because Moq matches generic arguments not exactly, but by assignment compatibility (see [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/e5197829d13567c7984362829db625da6662a32d/src/Moq/InvocationShape.cs#L80-L84) and [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/e5197829d13567c7984362829db625da6662a32d/src/Moq/Extensions.cs#L179-L212) if you're interested in the implementation), the following should just work:

```
public class BaseEvent { }
public class DerivedEvent1 : BaseEvent { }
public class DerivedEvent2 : BaseEvent { }

public interface IEvent
{
    void Subscribe<T>() where T : BaseEvent;
}


var eventMock = new Mock<IEvent>();

eventMock.Object.Subscribe<DerivedEvent1>();
eventMock.Object.Subscribe<DerivedEvent2>();

eventMock.Verify(m => m.Subscribe<BaseEvent>(), Times.Exactly(2));
```

Note how the `Verify` is phrased in terms of `BaseEvent`, but the actual calls made refer to two distinct derived types.

> This will pass, but it's using the derivied class.
>
> ```
> v.Subscribe<DerivedEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));
> ```
>
> This gets called zero times:
>
> ```
> v.Subscribe<BaseEvent>(), Times.Exactly(1));
> ```

You'd have to show more of your actual test code for further diagnosis why `BaseEvent`-based verification failed in your particular case.